# bteq ansi syntax execution error

Tags: unix, teradata

I'm trying to call a procedure via bteq but I keep getting a:

```
*** Error 3722 Only a COMMIT WORK or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.
```

Here is my code:

```
prvcy_call () { bteq << EOF
.set session transaction ansi;
$(cat $HOME/.tdlogon)
    DATABASE db;
    $1
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
EOF
}

prvcy_call "CALL PPROC.procedureAbcd (
        'p1',
        'p2',
        'p4',
        'p4' ;"
```

not sure whats wrong as it works in sql assistant..

I've tried this too:

```
prvcy_call "CALL PPROC.procedureAbcd (
        'p1',
        'p2',
        'p4',
        'p4' ;

        COMMIT;"
```

but get the same error

Comment: What's your procedure doing?  Are you inserting to a temp table and then trying to select from it, something like that?  And you may be able to get round this by setting your session to BTET instead of ansi.

Comment: You need to COMMIT the DATABASE command :-)